# I am getting the problem to start the VM instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When i am staring the VM instance it is giving me error

```
$ gcloud compute instances start wordpress-1-vm --zone=asia-south1-a
Starting instance(s) wordpress-1-vm...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) The zone 'projects/mobileyug/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again lat
er.
```

Then i have tried to move the instance it is giving me error noted below.

```
$ gcloud compute instances move wordpress-1-vm --zone=asia-south1-a --destination-zone=asia-south1-b
Moving gce instance wordpress-1-vm...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instance cannot be moved while in state: TERMINATED
```

Please suggest me how can i start my VM instance.

Answer (score 1):

1.Restart you vm instance and try again, because in TERMINATED state you can't interact with vm. 
From documentation:
TERMINATED - A user stopped the instance, or the instance encountered a failure. Start the instance again or delete it.

2.Try to move your instance manually:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually

3.If there is nothing important on this vm or it was newly created, just delete it and create in another zone (b or c)